# Python converting arbitrary output to table or list

Tags: python, networking, scripting, paramiko

I am writing a python script that will connect to Onboard Admin on HP C7000 chassis, lists all blade servers and based on name, determines the Bay ID, which it then uses to list internal switch port ID.

After logging in, and executing the 2nd part of the script (showing the actual port map). The response buffer would contain this long string.

```
b'show server port map 1\r\n              Mezz\r\nMezz   Mezz  Device  Port      Interconnect Interconnect\r\nSlot  Device  Port  Status         Bay        Bay Port       Device ID\r\n----  ------ ------ ---------- ------------ ------------ ----------------\r\n\r\n------------------------------- Blade 001 -------------------------------\r\n\r\n    1 QLogic QMH2562 8Gb FC HBA for HP BladeSystem c-Class\r\n            Port 1 OK            Bay 3        Port 1     50:01:43:80:21:db:8c:54\r\n            Port 2 OK            Bay 4        Port 1     50:01:43:80:21:db:8c:56\r\n\r\n    2 Not Present\r\n\r\n    3 Not Present\r\n\r\n      FlexFabric Embedded Ethernet\r\n Ethernet (NIC 1) LOM:1-a OK     Bay 1        Port 9     00:9C:02:AA:8C:58\r\niSCSI HBA (iSCSI 1) LOM:1-b OK   Bay 1        Port 9     00:9C:02:AA:8C:59\r\n  FCoE HBA LOM:1-b OK            Bay 1        Port 9     10:00:00:9C:02:AA:8C:59\r\n Ethernet (NIC 2) LOM:2-a OK     Bay 2        Port 9     00:9C:02:AA:8C:5C\r\niSCSI HBA (iSCSI 2) LOM:2-b OK   Bay 2        Port 9     00:9C:02:AA:8C:5D\r\n  FCoE HBA LOM:2-b OK            Bay 2        Port 9     10:00:00:9C:02:AA:8C:5D\r\n Ethernet (NIC 5) LOM:3-a OK     Bay 1        Port 1     00:9C:02:AA:8C:60\r\niSCSI HBA (iSCSI 3) LOM:3-b OK   Bay 1        Port 1     00:9C:02:AA:8C:61\r\n  FCoE HBA LOM:3-b OK            Bay 1        Port 1     10:00:00:9C:02:AA:8C:61\r\n Ethernet (NIC 6) LOM:4-a OK     Bay 2        Port 1     00:9C:02:AA:8C:64\r\niSCSI HBA (iSCSI 4) LOM:4-b OK   Bay 2        Port 1     00:9C:02:AA:8C:65\r\n  FCoE HBA LOM:4-b OK            Bay 2        Port 1     10:00:00:9C:02:AA:8C:65\r\n[maros@jump ~]$ '
```

Formatting this with .decode("utf-8") gives me more readable human output
[image]

What is interesting for me are the lines with MAC address, because they contain the Bay ID and Port ID. In nutshell I would like to break the output to individual lines, filter based on those which contain MAC address and extract the interesting info (Bay ID and Port ID). To make things harder the output could have slightly a different format like this:

[image]

What would be best way to approach this?

Comment: Did tried grepping? `grep -E 'mac1|man2|macN'

Comment: I believe this could work in *nix environment, but I would like to stay within this python script, I would like to use this output to perform another set of operations e.g. setting VLANs in these ports in each blade switch.

Answer (score 0):

This actually sounds pretty easy, if you do it with regex, because only the lines you are interested in, actually contain all the properties (bay id, port id and mac) together.

Imagine the following test (it could actually be written as one liner, but lets expand it to be easier to read):

```
import re
r=re.compile(r"\sPort\s+(\d+)\s+Bay\s+(\d+)\s+(([0-9A-F]{2}:){5,}..)")
for line in lines:
    m = r.match(line)
    if not m: continue
    print("We have bay %s slot %s mac %s"%(m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3))
```

Comment: I like this approach with expressions, but I have feeling that I need to repack that response from buffer, without it it treats each character as a line:
M
e
z
z
\
r
\
n
M
e
z
z
 
 
 
M
e
z
z
 
 
D
e
v
i
c
e
 
 
P
o
r
t

Comment: What you mean with repack? If the output is byte you need to encode it to string, and split by new lines. Then you can apply the above for loop a do whatever you want with the result...